# EMF format imported in Word looks worse in version 10

Tags: copy-as

In my work, I frequently use the "CopyAsMetafile" and "Paste" function in my Word document. Recently, I started working with Mathematica version 10 and negatively surprised that the display of metafile object pasted (graphics, text, etc) has a much lower quality than had version 9. Is there any way to improve visualization object pasted?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the problem you are talking about (screen shot from Word):

[image]

In Mathematica 9, the line thickness was less so it looked like this:

[image]

One thing you could try is to set the line thickness explicitly in Mathematica 10:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0]]
```

Then, it will look like this in Word:

[image]

Which is closer to what you might want.